# What's the difference between "<%" and "<%=" in embedded VBScript?

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I am working on a code base which as VBScript code embedded in HTML.  I've noticed the following two different tags around said lines of code

```
<%= MyFunc(val1) %>
```

and

```
<% MyFunc(val1) %>
```

What is the difference in using the "=" character at the beginning of these sections?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<%` evaluates an expression in server code but doesn't emit output.

`<%=` also evaluates the expression but wraps the result in Response.Write, so it produces output.

Comment: Genius.  That makes sense with what I'm seeing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you see:

`<%= MyFunc() %>`

it really means:

```
<%
Response.Write( MyFunc() )
%>
```

Its short hand for writting output to the response.

```
<%
MyFunc()
%>
```

The above will just run the code but won't write it to the response unless it has some `Response.Write`'s inside the Function/Sub itself.